# Ubuntu not detecting my HDMI monitor

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, hdmi, 21.04

My computer has ubuntu 21.04, it is not detecting my HDMI monitor. I've already tried the following solutions:

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` && `sudo systemctl start gdm3`
2. `sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia*'` &&`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers` && `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
4. `sudo apt install gnome` && `sudo service gdm3 restart` && `sudo reboot`

But they didn't solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I tried other solutions that I don't remember. But, I managed to get the computer to detect the second monitor with the following steps:

1. I disconnect the HDMI cable
2. restart my computer
3. After booting, I connected the HDMI cable. After that the computer recognized the second screen.

I don't know if something else I did generated the fix. But only after these steps did my computer detect the second screen.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this same problem, and and fixed it by first enabling, and then re-disabling secure boot in the UEFI settings.

Answer (score 1):

I installed 21.04 on my pi4b ok, but after I did 3 things, update, upgrade, and installed OpenSSH, the display moved to the second HDMI port.  So, shortly after boot, the display goes away (NO SIGNAL).  I left the cable on the second port and called it good.